# Discord Bot - 'discord' has no attribute 'Select'

Tags: drop-down-menu, discord, menu, discord.py, chatbot

discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'menu' raised an exception: AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Select'

My code:

```py
@tree.command(guild=discord.Object(id=id_do_servidor), name='menu', description='Menu')
async def sm(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(
        "Escolha uma opção:",
        components=[
            discord.Select(
                placeholder="Selecione algo",
                options=[
                    discord.SelectOption(label="Opção 1", value="1"),
                    discord.SelectOption(label="Opção 2", value="2"),
                    discord.SelectOption(label="Opção 3", value="3")
                ]
            )
        ]
    )

    interaction = await tree.wait_for("select_option")
    await interaction.respond(content=f"Você selecionou a opção {interaction.values[0]}")
```

Trying to do a discord menu for chatbot, dropdown menu specifically.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @BlueRobin I want to do a dropdown menu for my discord bot, but this error pops up, not only that error but other from discord_enums to

if you have some dropdown menu or something like that, would be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

The error should be self-explanatory

> module 'discord' has no attribute 'Select'

If you'd type in `select` in the docs, you'd see that it indeed doesn't exist: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=select

It's under `ui`, so it should be accessed as `discord.ui.Select` instead.

On a side note:

> `interaction = await tree.wait_for("select_option")`

This doesn't make too much sense. You may want to look at the [official dropdown example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/dropdown.py).